# How can I store one result from a Get-ChildItem as one array value?

Tags: powershell

I have a folder named D:\MyDir, and this is its content:

```
PS D:\MyDir> gci


    Directory: D:\MyDir


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ---- d-----       11/22/2021   8:10 PM                MyFolder-2021-11-22
```

I'm storing the folder's name ordered by creatin on $Dirlist:

```
$Dirlist = gci $LBDestination | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime | select -Property Name | foreach { $_.Name }
```

The problem I am having is that the system is storing each letter of my listing as one value in my array

```
PS D:\MyDir> $Dirlist[0..3]
M
y
F
o
```

When I have more than one folder my script works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not a good practice to use `format-list` for handling data. `format-list` is for visualizing output.

Instead, you should tell your variable that it definetly is an array, even if it has only one value. You can do that by casting it to a `[string[]]` or by wrapping your entire command into `@()` which makes it an array even before it's stored in the variable.

See the difference here:

Your way works if there is more than one return, since then it automatically is an array. However it does not work if there is only a single return, since PowerShell thinks you want your Variable to be a string, because you don't specifically tell it that you want it to be an array:

```
PS C:\Install\mydir> $Dirlist = gci . | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime | select -ExpandProperty Name
PS C:\Install\mydir> $Dirlist[0..3]
M
y
F
o
```

You can cast it to an array and it will work:

```
PS C:\Install\mydir> [string[]]$Dirlist = gci . | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime | select -ExpandProperty Name
PS C:\Install\mydir> $Dirlist[0..3]
MyFolder-2021-11-22
```

Or wrap the entire command in `@()`:

```
PS C:\Install\mydir> $Dirlist = @(gci . | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime | select -ExpandProperty Name)
PS C:\Install\mydir> $Dirlist[0..3]
MyFolder-2021-11-22
```

btw. instead of

- `| select -Property Name | foreach { $_.Name }`

just use

- `| select -ExpandProperty Name`

Comment: Why is not a good practice to use format-list?

What is the difference between using "| select -ExpandProperty Name"?

Comment: @WayneHamilton `Format-List` works in this case because you have single strings as an array. however if you have multiple properties etc. it won't work anymore as you expect it. as I said it's for visualizing data, just for you to look at it, not for handling and manipulating data. it would be a bad habit if you think now "oh i can just `fl` everything". So don't use it at all for such cases, it's simply not correct. the `select` i wrote is just more elegant because it expands the property directly and you don't need to iterate it with `foreach`. it does exactly the same but is more elegant.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @SimonS.

Answer (score 3):

I just added a format-list (ft is the short version) in the end and it worked for me:

```
$Dirlist= gci $LBDestination | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime | select -Property Name | foreach { $_.Name } | fl
```